# How does jQuery's val(value) set the selected value in a dropdownbox (underwater)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 3 and jQuery 1.5.

Somewhere in my code I use jQuery to set the selected value of a dropdownbox like so:

```
$("#SelectedFilterOption").val(filterOption)
```

`filterOption` is the value of the option field, not the text. On my screen I see the right value as selected, however, when I look at the html, I do not see any option element with the `selected` attribute set. When I post these values to to my ASP.NET MVC 3 app, how do "they" know what value is selected?

**Edit:**
`$("#SelectedFilterOption").val()` does return the right value. Also I noticed that when I set the initial selected value from ASP.NET MVC, that element *will* get the `selected` attribute. The selecte dattribute stays on the field in the html, even when I manually select another option.

I will inspect this with firebug as well (in addition to chrome and IE9 tools).

Comment: Did you use Firebug to look at the html? If not use it so you can the html code at runtime.

Comment: I used chrome and IE9's DOM inspectors (In IE9 I did press refresh html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It finds the index of the first item with that value.

When it has the index, it uses `<select>`'s `.selectedIndex=targetIndexNumber` property via DOM. Editing the html is not required. Some browsers do that themselves, others don't bother.

Comment: Aha, and that value gets posted. What happens when I use jQuery to just add the `selected` attribute to a specific option instead of using `val()`? Will the correct value still be posted?

Comment: @Matthijs, adding `selected` to an option will have the same effect. It will select that option for all needs and purposes..